# How to add a custom CSS file in Magento's Admin Area

Tags: magento

I want to load a custom CSS file in Magento's Admin Area. My approach is to do it exactly as I would in the frontend:

```
<action method="addCss">
    <file>namespace/module/mycss.css</file>
</action>
```

That generates the following `<link>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="http://host/skin/adminhtml/base/default/namespace/module/mycss.css" 
    media="all">
```

That tells me that Magento is looking for my CSS in `/skin/adminhtml/base/default/namespace/module`. So if I put it there, I'd probably be fine and everything would work.

But that just doesn't seem like the *proper* way to do it since `/skin/adminhtml/base` doesn't even exist.

The whole thing seems even weirder to me when I look at a core module like `Mage_Widget`. It adds CSS files the exact same way:

```
<action method="addCss"><name>lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css</name></action>
```

But that file is stored unter /skin/adminhtml/**default**/default/lib/...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `<file>` to `<name>`, as done in the `Mage_Widget` core module.

Comment: @Axel - node names do not matter in this position.

Answer (score 7):

*base/default* is the appropriate location for this file. It is the ultimate fallback regardless of design area. It would not be inappropriate to provide theme assets under *default/default* given the precedent from the core team. If present in the latter of these two themes, the link would be generated for that path before the former.

Incidentally, if you rename *app/design/adminhtml/default* to *app/design/adminhtml/base* the admin theme works fine.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to skin/adminhtml/default/default and place your file under module/custom.css
2. Go to app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout and create the file module.xml with the following code:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <layout>
>     <default>
>         <reference name="head">
>             <action method="addCss">
>                 <name>module/custom.css</name>
>             </action>
>         </reference>
>     </default>
> </layout>
> ```

3. Now connect your xml file to the module in Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml:

> ```
> <config>
> ...
> <adminhtml>
>     <layout>
>         <updates>
>             <namespace_module>
>                 <file>module.xml</file>
>             </namespace_module>
>         </updates>
>     </layout>
> </adminhtml>
> ...
> </config>
> ```

Cheers

Comment: This is much understandable

Comment: But I have one doubt that custom folder will be lost when magento version will be updated. I need to add custom js only in module folder itself Or even better please tell me the best solution to add custom js for admin custom module so that we will not lost anything even after updating magento.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Incidentally, if you rename app/design/adminhtml/default to
>   app/design/adminhtml/base the admin theme works fine.

@benmarks answer is correct although incomplete. You need to rename another directory too: `skin/adminhtml/default` to `skin/adminhtml/base`

I created a custom theme for admin so I could handle header insertions etc.

So I had to change the `config.xml` in my module to look like:

```
<config>
<stores>
    <admin>
        <!-- altering admin design package and theme -->
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>MY_THEME_PACKAGE_NAME</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>default</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
</config>
```

## Edit

I found that just renaming the `adminhtml/default/default` theme dir to `adminhtml/base/default` and the `skin` folder as I suggested **breaks** quick product creation in configurable products section of admin.

I ended up copying a `mymodule_layoutfile.xml` (could be a `local.xml` file, I just didn't want to put a file without reference to my module) to both `adminhtml/default/default/layout` and `frontend/base/default/layout` dirs.

Notice that `adminhtml` doesn't have a `base` directory, so `default/default` is used.

The `mymodule_layoutfile.xml` contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.noConflict.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Double check if the path is absolutely correct. In my case I had namespace/module/css/mycss.css. I missed css folder and because Magento couldn't find it inside default folder, it went to base folder.